# unique constraint violated on Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to generate random data into Oracle table:

First table

```
-- TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
/

 CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP1 ON AGENT_HISTORY (AGENTID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE AGENT_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY8 PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)
/
```

Second table

```
-- TABLE CPU_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE CPU_HISTORY(
  CPU_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CPU_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/
```

I tried to create this PL/SQL block:

```
Error starting at line : 1,690 in command -
BEGIN

FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
LOOP
   INSERT INTO CPU_HISTORY_ID (CPU_HISTORY_ID, EVENT_ID, CPU_NAME, CPU_VALUE) VALUES (loop_counter, loop_counter, 'cpu1', dbms_random.value(1,100));
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Error

```
  Error report -
    ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
    Error starting at line : 1,680 in command -
```

second PL/SQL block

```
BEGIN

FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
LOOP
   INSERT INTO AGENT_HISTORY (EVENT_ID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE) VALUES (loop_counter, 22, SYSDATE);
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

error

```
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.KEY8) violated
ORA-06512: at line 5
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Can you give me some advice where I'm wrong?

Is there another way to generate 1000 rows with random values into the tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error if because the table you are inserting in is `CPU_HISTORY_ID` but it should be `CPU_HISTORY`.

The second error is probably caused because that table is already populated with data. Did you execute the second PL twice without deleting the data?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as valid :)